# How to create dataset from Object?

Tags: c#, json, datatable, dataset

I have JSON representing an object. The object could be for example an array of objects of type company and each company contains an array of type employee.

I want to take the array of companies use it as input and on the output get two tables: `companiesTable` and `employeesTable`. Each employee should also have a link to the corresponding company. So, I'm looking for function where I can put object serialized in JSON, RelationShips between entities - (employees should have defined link to their company). The result of the call should be two tables.

Comment: Have you tried `newtonsoft`? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: The problem is that I don't know type of the object in JSON and also I rather need tables representing entities, than deserialized object. I know newtonsoft json, but not all possibilities of it.

Comment: Then what about https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm and https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDataSet.htm?  What have you tried?  What does your JSON look like?