# How to convert Multiple Json object to DataTable or DataSet in C#

Tags: c#

I have an below json object.I would to know 2 points

1. How to convert below json object to DataTable or Dataset in C# Code
2. After converting,reverse back to (How to convert DataTable to Json object)  in C# Code.
   Please provide me example code

```json
[
  {
    "transaction": {
      "Version": "1.01",
      "TranDtls": {
        "TaxSch": "GST",
        "SupTyp": "B2B",
        "RegRev": "Y",
        "EcmGstin": null,
        "IgstOnIntra": "N"
      },
      "DocDtls": {
        "Typ": "INV",
        "No": "DAOC/007",
        "Dt": "10/08/2020"
      },
      "SellerDtls": {
        "Gstin": "29AAFCD5862R000",
        "LglNm": "NIC company pvt ltd",
        "TrdNm": "NIC Industries",
        "Addr1": "5th block, kuvempu layout",
        "Addr2": "kuvempu layout",
        "Loc": "GANDHINAGAR",
        "Pin": 560037,
        "Stcd": "29",
        "Ph": "9000000000",
        "Em": "abc@gmail.com"
      },
      "BuyerDtls": {
        "Gstin": "29AWGPV7107B1Z1",
        "LglNm": "XYZ company pvt ltd",
        "TrdNm": "XYZ Industries",
        "Pos": "12",
        "Addr1": "7th block, kuvempu layout",
        "Addr2": "kuvempu layout",
        "Loc": "GANDHINAGAR",
        "Pin": 562160,
        "Stcd": "29",
        "Ph": "91111111111",
        "Em": "xyz@yahoo.com"
      },
      "DispDtls": {
        "Nm": "ABC company pvt ltd",
        "Addr1": "7th block, kuvempu layout",
        "Addr2": "kuvempu layout",
        "Loc": "Banagalore",
        "Pin": 562160,
        "Stcd": "29"
      },
      "ShipDtls": {
        "Gstin": "29AWGPV7107B1Z1",
        "LglNm": "CBE company pvt ltd",
        "TrdNm": "kuvempu layout",
        "Addr1": "7th block, kuvempu layout",
        "Addr2": "kuvempu layout",
        "Loc": "Banagalore",
        "Pin": 562160,
        "Stcd": "29"
      },
      "ItemList": [
        {
          "SlNo": "1",
          "PrdDesc": "Rice",
          "IsServc": "N",
          "HsnCd": "1001",
          "Barcde": "123456",
          "Qty": 100.345,
          "FreeQty": 10,
          "Unit": "BAG",
          "UnitPrice": 99.545,
          "TotAmt": 9988.84,
          "Discount": 10,
          "PreTaxVal": 1,
          "AssAmt": 9978.84,
          "GstRt": 12.0,
          "IgstAmt": 1197.46,
          "CgstAmt": 0,
          "SgstAmt": 0,
          "CesRt": 5,
          "CesAmt": 498.94,
          "CesNonAdvlAmt": 10,
          "StateCesRt": 12,
          "StateCesAmt": 1197.46,
          "StateCesNonAdvlAmt": 5,
          "OthChrg": 10,
          "TotItemVal": 12897.7,
          "OrdLineRef": "3256",
          "OrgCntry": "AG",
          "PrdSlNo": "12345",
          "BchDtls": {
            "Nm": "123456",
            "ExpDt": "01/08/2020",
            "WrDt": "01/09/2020"
          },
          "AttribDtls": [
            {
              "Nm": "Rice",
              "Val": "10000"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "ValDtls": {
        "AssVal": 9978.84,
        "CgstVal": 0,
        "SgstVal": 0,
        "IgstVal": 1197.46,
        "CesVal": 508.94,
        "StCesVal": 1202.46,
        "Discount": 10,
        "OthChrg": 20,
        "RndOffAmt": 0.3,
        "TotInvVal": 12908,
        "TotInvValFc": 12897.7
      },
      "PayDtls": {
        "Nm": "ABCDE",
        "AccDet": "5697389713210",
        "Mode": "Cash",
        "FininsBr": "SBIN11000",
        "PayTerm": "100",
        "PayInstr": "Gift",
        "CrTrn": "test",
        "DirDr": "test",
        "CrDay": 100,
        "PaidAmt": 10000,
        "PaymtDue": 5000
         },
      "RefDtls": {
        "InvRm": "TEST",
        "DocPerdDtls": {
          "InvStDt": "01/08/2020",
          "InvEndDt": "01/09/2020"
        },
        "PrecDocDtls": [
          {
            "InvNo": "DOC/002",
            "InvDt": "01/08/2020",
            "OthRefNo": "123456"
          }
        ],
        "ContrDtls": [
          {
            "RecAdvRefr": "Doc/003",
            "RecAdvDt": "01/08/2020",
            "Tendrefr": "Abc001",
            "Contrrefr": "Co123",
            "Extrefr": "Yo456",
            "Projrefr": "Doc-456",
            "Porefr": "Doc-789",
            "PoRefDt": "01/08/2020"
          }
        ]
      },
      "AddlDocDtls": [
        {
          "Url": "https://einv-apisandbox.nic.in",
          "Docs": "Test Doc",
          "Info": "Document Test"
        }
      ],
      "ExpDtls": {
        "ShipBNo": "A-248",
        "ShipBDt": "01/08/2020",
        "Port": "INABG1",
        "RefClm": "N",
        "ForCur": "AED",
        "CntCode": "AE"
      },
      "EwbDtls": {
        "TransId": "12AWGPV7107B1Z1",
        "TransName": "XYZ EXPORTS",
        "Distance": 100,
        "TransDocNo": "DOC01",
        "TransDocDt": "10/08/2020",
        "VehNo": "ka123456",
        "VehType": "R",
        "TransMode": "1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You don't include your attempt but you do include reams of unformatted JSON. -1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is not a code request site. If you need help with code, you will need to show what you have done so far, describe what you don't understand, describe the output of the code, and tell us what you would like it to do instead.

Comment: read this  newtonsoft json https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it here [How to create dataset from Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47940802/how-to-create-dataset-from-object)

There are a lot of ways you can use to instantiate an object from json string.

If you can't use any kind of third party libraries such as Newtonsoft.Json you can do it with **JsonReaderWriterFactory**

```
public static TEntity Create<TEntity>(string json)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        byte[] jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        memoryStream.Write(jsonBytes, 0, jsonBytes.Length);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var jsonReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(
            memoryStream,
            Encoding.UTF8,
            XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max,
            null))
        {
            var     serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TEntity));
            TEntity entity     = (TEntity)serializer.ReadObject(jsonReader);
            return entity;
        }
    }
}
```

And vice-versa

```
public static string Create(object entity)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(entity.GetType());

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, entity);
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Then you will only need to work a little bit with C# to populate the required DataSet with your object instance.

[Here is my code](https://github.com/zanybaka/StackOverflow.com/tree/master/Questions/63742762/ConsoleApp1)

Comment: Thanks for above code, can you have code for dataset instead of entity